# Apache tries to connect to local network when connecting through the internet

Tags: apache, ubuntu, owncloud

I have installed Apache on an Ubuntu server. It works perfectly from my local network but when i try to connect from another place i have this problem.
First of all i have created a no-ip host so i can have a url. When i put that url or my public ip in another computer it connects me to my home page but when i click on a link the browser tries to connect to 192.168.1.64/folder (computers IP and folder of links name).
The link i want it to get me to is an owncloud installation. I have tried a lot of different things but still can't get it to work.

Comment: What is the `ServerName` set to in Apache's configuration?

Comment: In the fqdn it's like this: ServerName localhost

Answer (score 1):

You could give `‘trusted_domains’ =>  array ( 0 => ‘A.B.C.D ‘,),` in the `owncloud.conf a try. 
http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/admin_manual/config/default_parameters.html